# "Touch a point on the screen" or "touch ON a point on the screen"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

I have difficulty understanding the difference between these two phrases.

Does “touch (an item)” express a more general meaning — I mean, is it used when you do not specify the item? For example: “Touch a point (anywhere on the screen)”?
Is “touch ON (an item)” used when the item is specified? For example: “Touch on the point (this point) on the screen.”?

Comment: Screens are getting complicated. You do *touch + something* for a touchscreen whereas with a mouse you *click + on + something*. Then, just when you get these down, on come the 3D VR screens...

Answer (score 2):

You don't *touch on* something, you *touch* something. The following sentence is correct.

> Touch a point on the screen.

The only context I can think of where this rule would not apply is if you were referring to a speech that *touched on* a topic, but that doesn't have anything to do with physical touching.